Where do people recommend I go to buy the essential equipment I'll need, only having Basic Qulification?
I'm new to ham radio and only have basic qualification. I'm mainly looking to communicate regionally within Alberta but I'm not sure where to go or even start for gathering the equipment I'll need for the type of communicating I'd like to do. Any ideas on what I'll need to again communicate regionally and remotely? Is there a common local frequency used in Alberta?

Since you're in Alberta, I'd recommend https://ve6lk.com/ to start.

Also https://www.rac.ca/western-region/ for one or more clubs near you that may have local info.

PS: typically you'd want to post separate questions for each topic on StackOverflow. Might want to break this one up or edit it so it can have a single answer.
